# A python syntax error that cannot find and answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, args, keyword-argument

def calculate_money_made(**trips):
    total_money_made = 0

```
for trip_id, trip from trips.items():
    trip_revenue = trip.cost - trip.driver.cost
    total_money_made += trip_revenue

return total_money_made
```

gives an error! cannot figure out
File "script.py", line 41
    for trip_id, trip from trips.items():
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What is trips, a dictionary ?

Comment: it's not **from** its **in** in the  for loop

Answer (score 1):

Change "from" to "in" 
`for trip_id, trip in trip.items():`